# Como cargar solo un cuadro de una pantalla con PHP o AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo una ventana con 4 recuadros que me traen gráficas, estoy realizando un dashboard de solo gráficas para reportes y estoy usando HTML, MYSQL, JAVASCRIPT y PHP.

Esto seria mi codigo de la pantalla general tablero.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Sistema | Dashboard</title>
    </head>
<body>

Y por medio de un incluide llamo a la gráfica:

<?php
    include('flot190.php');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hasta allí todo muy bien, el problema es que esa gráfica tiene un menú con 3 botones para filtrar por otros datos. este seria el menu que estan dentro de -flot190.php-

```
<table>
<tr>
<th><font color="#ffffff">FILTROS:</font> 

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='320'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado">320</a>

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='240'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado">240</a>

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='190'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado">190</a>
</tr>
</table>
```

Entonces al momento de seleccionar un filtro osea algún botón me recarga toda la pantalla nuevamente y quisiera es que se recargue solo ese cuadro de la grafica y no toda la pantalla.

De que forma podría hacerlo y con cual lenguaje.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: no uses enlaces entonces , usa eventos de raton como click y cuando se pulse , puedes hacer una peticion http a la url de la pantalla y añadir los datos a la tabla

Comment: Tienes algún ejemplo que sea un poco más claro? por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tablero.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Sistema | Dashboard</title>
    </head>
<body>

Y por medio de un incluide llamo a la gráfica:

<?php
    include('flot190.php');
?>
<div id="grafica"></div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('#filtro').click(function () {
    let HTML= `aca va lo que quieres que aparezca en el div grafica`; 
     document.getElementById().innerHTML=HTML;
  });
$('#filtro2').click(function () {
    let HTML= `aca va lo que quieres que aparezca en el div grafica`; 
     document.getElementById().innerHTML=HTML;
  });
$('#filtro3').click(function () {
    let HTML= `aca va lo que quieres que aparezca en el div grafica`; 
     document.getElementById().innerHTML=HTML;
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

float190.php

```
<table>
<tr>
<th><font color="#ffffff">FILTROS:</font> 

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='320'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado" id="filtro">320</a>


<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='240'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado" id="filtro2">240</a>

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='190'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado" id="filtro3">190</a>
</tr>
</table>
```